# Geometrical intuition behind different representations of line segment counting

Tags: geometry, intuition

So I was doing a random proof from Transition to Advanced Mathematics; it goes as follows:

Let $P_1, P_2,... P_n$ be *n* points in a plane with no three points collinear. Show that the number of line segments joining all pairs of points is $(n^2 - n) / 2$.

I played around with the problem for a while and I ended up writing the following recurrence: $$F(1) = 0 \\ F(n + 1) = n + F(n)$$

The intuition behind this is that each and every additional point added (not collinear-ly with any other two) simply adds a line segment with each point already present in the plane, which is directly expressed as $F(n)$ which is the amount without the new point and $+\ n$ which is the number of new segments, hence the recurrence. (Note the n + 1 for the second equation.)

Then I noticed that the recurrence relation simply unfolds to: $$F(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}i$$

The intuition behind this one is now rather apparent, as the total number of segments is just the sum of all the segments between points, and we always form $n-1$ new points with each *nth* point.

So far so good. However, while the term $(n^2 - n) / 2$ is certainly equivalent to the other two I've mentioned (proof by straightforward induction on *n*, and just rather apparent algebraically), I fail to see how one could intuitively come up with it from the geometrical representation of adding points to a plane. Is there a good way to look at this geometrically, or is the term *in this particular scenario* just an "artefact"?

Technical note: My question has arisen while looking at this particular proof toy problem, yet I am not asking about the proof itself.

Comment: "parts of points"? Pairs of points, isn't it?

Comment: @zoli indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incrementally from *adding* point in the plane it's hard to reach the non-recursive term $(n^2-n)/2$. But if you look at all $n$ points in a static setup, you could argue like this:

A line is connecting two points. So take any of the $n$ points as starting point, and any as end point of the line segment. Thus $n^2$ possible pairs. But that includes $n$ pairs where both endpoints are the same; we should remove them. And then our lines are undirected, so the pair $(A,B)$ and the pair $(B,A)$ are the same line. We counted each line twice, so we divide the sum by two.

Somtimes it's easier to think about connecting each point in the plane to each *other* point. In that case you end up with the equivalent $n(n-1)/2$.